# Issue accessing URL in JsonArrayRequest when compileSdkVersion is upgraded to 28

Tags: android

When compileSdkVersion is 27, it works fine, but when compileSdkVersion is 
changed to 28, the url is not getting accessed.

My code

```
public void getCategory(final OnCategoryReceived onCategoryReceived) {
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://my-domin.ir/api/getcategory", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            /*  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
            List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                Category category = new Category();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    category.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                    category.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    category.setImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                    categories.add(category);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            onCategoryReceived.onReceived(categories);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
}
```

Comment: then what it does in API 28, if it does not take thew url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from Android 9 (28 - Pie Version), Android disabled cleartext traffic support. I had the same issue in my android for Android 9 version. I have only added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In my `<Application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` and it's working fine for me in 28 (9-Pie).

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

You will need to  Create file **res/xml/network_security_config.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your URL(ex: 127.0.0.1)</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and set below code in manifest.xml to allow clear text.

**AndroidManifest.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```